# Chapter 7 Ruby on Rails users_controller.rb error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I followed all the instructions in chapter 7 Ruby on Rails tutorial, when I finally run $ Bundle exec rspec spec/ a series of errors are being displayed. I doubled checked if my codes had any spelling mistakes or any symbols left out. Everything seems to fine. Could you please kindly interpret the errors and tell me where I am going wrong??? Thanks

**USER_PAGES_SPEC.RB**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
  before {visit signup_path}

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign ') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

 describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

   describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving a user" do
        before {click_button submit}

        let (:user) {user.find_by_email("user@example.com")}

        it {should have_selector('title', text:user.name)}
    end
  end
end
end
```

**USER_CONTROLLER.RB**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save

    sign_in @user

    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"

    redirect_to @user

    else

     render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

**ERRORS DISPLAYED ON COMMAND LINE**

```
    3) User pages signup page
 ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mit { should have_selector('title', text: full_
```

title('Sign up')) }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Neste
d_2::Nested_1:0x461b260>←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11:in`block (3 levels) in '←[0m

4) User pages profile page
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mit { should have_selector('title', text: user.
name) }←[0m
       ←[31mexpected css "title" with text "Michael Hartl" to return something←[
0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in '←[0m

5) User pages signup with valid information should create a user
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mexpect { click_button submit }.to change(User,
 :count).by(1)←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `sign_in' for #<UsersController:0x45a8f00>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in`create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in`block (5 levels) in '←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in '←[0m

6) User pages signup with valid information after saving a user
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore {click_button submit}←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `sign_in' for #<UsersController:0x46341c0>←[0m
←[36m     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in`create'←[0m
←[36m     # (eval):2:in `click_button'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in`block (5 levels) in '←[0m

Comment: Do you have a `models/user.rb`?

Comment: @muistooshort Hi Thanks for the help. I thought my user.rb file was saved but apparently it wasnt!

But I have new 4 errors :( , I have updated the query with the new errors , if you get a chance please kindly help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1) undefined method full_title

Are you defined it?

> 2) expected css "title" with text "Michael Hartl" to return something

You haven't `<title>Michael Hartl</title>` in output html.

> 3, 4) undefined method sign_in

Where are you defined it?

Correct your code and all tests will be passed.

Comment: Hi Jan 

Thanks for your help. I finally found the error. In the earlier chapter I had to omit " <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title> " which comes under app/views/layouts/application.html.erb  in order to pass the test. I went through all my files and re-inserted the code. And the test passed successfully :)